# Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file

Tags: android, android-layout, gradle, android-library

After Updating to the **gradle 3.1.4** and moving to **buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"**

I'm Facing this issues

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class ImageView

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class ImageView
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.demo.android:drawable/ic_demo with resource ID #0x7f080160
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_demo.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f080160
```

I tried to replace android:src to app:srcCompat and added
 **vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true in defaultConfig**

Below is the layout file code

```
<RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/demo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_demo"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**UPDATE:**
I found an issue. issue is some of the vector are working and some of them are not supported though they are created in SVG format from same sources. Can anyone suggest me to convert the PNG to SVG FILE.

Comment: Make sure your image `/ic_demo` is in **`res/drawable`** folder not in **`drawable-v24`**

Comment: Paste your xml code. Very difficult to debug without haveing a look at it. Check if you're getting an error in xml

Comment: can't find resource in your project error means

Comment: use `AppCompatImageView` rather than `ImageView`, that might solve your issue.

Comment: do not use this app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_demo" use : android:src

Comment: @NileshRathod it's already in res/drawable not in v21 or v24 still i'm facing that issue

Comment: Do not use app:src="@drawable/abc" use android:src="@drawable/abc" as @Abhinav Gupta suggested

Comment: is ic_demo a vector drawable?

Comment: @KaranMer it's in svg format.

Comment: Ive run into the same thing and tried all of the appCompat vs notCompat solutions. The problem does seem to be that some svgs do not convert into useable xml. The Android Studio image preview shows the image perfectly but it crashes in the app. Replacing it with another svg->xml image fixes the problem. So... I think the problem is that the Vector Studio in AS cant handle some features of an actual SVG. Perhaps textures or something. Its not something you are doing wrong. Ask your graphic artist to minimize the features in the svg.

Answer (score 1):

if your image is a vector drawable make sure you have done below code.

In your app's build.gradle add:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}
```

And for vector support for less then API 21, add the following to onCreate:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
```

Also, Replace your `ImageView` with `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView`

Comment: can you generate vector graphic from android studio and test with that image. looks like your vector graphic might not be supported.

Comment: it used to work on below gradle 3.0 but from today i'm facing this issue.

Comment: Found an issue. some of the vector are not supported and some of them are. but in lower version all of the vector used to work perfectly.
can you suggest some me how do i convert PNG to SVG?

Comment: you can check supported tags for backwards compatibility from this link. https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio

Answer (score 0):

The drawable `ic_demo` can't be found.  
Make sure that this drawable is in `res/drawable` folder and not in another folder like `drawable-v21` or `drawable-v24`

Comment: it's already in res/drawable not in v21 or v24 still i'm facing that issue

Comment: Then clean project and if needed invalidate/restart

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_demo"
```

with

```
android:src="@drawable/ic_demo"
```